# Ruby On Rails add script which inserts a random value into a certain column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table named "Grades" which contains 2 columns: "Name" and "Grade".
I have already filled the Name field manually (I have about 150 records), and now I want to randomize a grade for each student.

I don't want to use mysql syntax, I want to use ruby code.
Could you please tell me how to do it and where this script should be placed in the ruby direcory tree?

Later on I plan to replace the code that randomizes the grades with a more complicated code that calculates them (it's just a temporary implnementation)...

(I'm new in Ruby and I want to do things correctly).

Comment: Are you using Rails or plain Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a rake task that loops through all the records and inserts a random number into the field. That way you can run it whenever you want.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/66-custom-rake-tasks

Comment: Thanks, I will watch the cast (they are great). Where do you place those "tasks" files (in the directory tree structure)?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create test data for your development env, you should use seeds. You can find it in `db/seeds.rb`. This file contains some examples.
And if you want to do in right way you should use syntax like this

```
names = ['Mark', 'Paul', 'Alex', 'Phil']
150.times do |i|
  # create! throw exception if errors  
  Grade.create!(name: names.sample, grade: rand(6))
end
```

If you want do this operation(update grade column) usually, use rake tasks.

Comment: Since OP already seems to have existing records, I would suggest to use `Grade.all.each { |grade| grade.update_attribute(:grade, rand(6)) }` instead.